# how to import partition data from s3 to presto

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, presto

I have data stored in S3 in form of csv files with partitions. I am trying to read this data using presto. I am able to read data if I give the complete location of csv file with partition. Below is the query to read data from a "month":

```
create table default.test(
    name varchar, 
    age varchar, 
    section varchar, 
    year varchar,
    month varchar,
    day varchar,
    hour varchar
)
WITH (partitioned_by = ARRAY['year','month','day','hour'], 
external_location = 's3://bucket/presto/2021/01', 
format = 'csv'
);
```

The table is being created but when I try to select the data the table is empty.
please help